# Sorting results of ps by start time

Tags: unix, sorting, ps

I'm displaying information about the current processes using this variety of the `ps` command:

```
ps -eo pid,start,stime,command
```

**How can I sort these results by start?**

I've read `man ps` and tried `-m`, `-r` and `-v` sorting options. Unfortunately I haven't been able to use these options to sort by start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `etime`. That's elapsed time, in days, hours, etc. which is suitable for sorting numerically. If it's the first column, I think ps will sort by it automatically.

Otherwise, you can override sort order by using `--sort`, but make sure it is after the `-o` option, example:

```
ps -o pid,user:32,start,etime,state,time,vsz,args --sort=etime
```

Comment: weird - guess it's coincidental for me, since I'm running on a recently-booted machine. Just pipe to sort -n, then.

Comment: @MrMusic: not for uptime > 24 hours

Comment: @BobbyJack good point. In my case I'm interested in differentiating processes started within the last hour or so from days or months ago.